Get posts by query excluding the current month
How would I get custom posts by a WordPress query that excludes the current month? I have a query created that shows the posts published in the current month...
<?php
   $currentYear    =   date('Y');
   $currentMonth   =   date('n');

   $args_current_month = array(
     'post_type'         =>  'post',
     'post_status'       =>  array('publish', 'future'),
     'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
     'date_query'        =>  array(
        array(
          'year'      =>  $currentYear,
          'month'     =>  $currentMonth
        )
     )
   );
   $current_month_query = new WP_Query($args_current_month);
?>

But how would I do a query for the opposite and exclude the posts published within the current month?
I tried the below query and was expecting it to exclude the posts in the current month but it doesn't...
<?php $currentMonthPosts = array(
  'post_status'       =>  array('publish', 'future'),
  'date_query'        =>  array(
    array(
      'year'      =>  $currentYear,
      'month'     =>  $currentMonth
    )
  )
 );
 $args_future = array(
    'post_type'         =>  'post',
    'post_status'       =>  array('future'),
    'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
    'post__not_in'      =>  $currentMonthPosts,
  );
$future_query = new WP_Query($args_future);`
?>


I think your answer can be found in the documentation:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters
You can set a date range and get all posts within the specified dates.
Example: get all posts in this year except this month.
<?php 

// Start date 
list($y1,$m1,$d1) = explode('-', date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last day of december last year')));

// Limit date
list($y2,$m2,$d2) = explode('-', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of this month')));

// Build the parameters

$args = array(
     'post_type'         =>  'post',
     'post_status'       =>  array('publish', 'future'),
     'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
     'date_query'        =>  array(
      'after'     => array('year' => $y1, 'month' => $m1, 'day' => $d1),
      'before'    => array('year' => $y2, 'month' => $m2, 'day' => $d2),
      'inclusive' => true,
     )
   );


$query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

I hope it helps. Thanks


Using before you can achieve this, source: WordPress Date Query
Code:
<?php

   $args_current_month = array(
     'post_type'         =>  'post',
     'post_status'       =>  array('publish', 'future'),
     'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
     'date_query'        =>  array(
        array(
          'before' => date('Y-m-01'),
        )
     )
   );
   $current_month_query = new WP_Query($args_current_month);
?>

P.S: @Luuk helped with improvements to the answer.

"The number 2592000 represents the amount of seconds in a month" ???  I always thought that February has less seconds than December (not only because of Christmas....)

@Luuk you're actually right, I didn't use the correct word, it's actually the number of seconds in 30 days, I'll edit my answer thanks

But simply getting the The first day of the current month would be better than -30*24*3600

Thanks for that @Luuk, answer was updated
